# How to match a number if it is not in between two _ characters like _1234_

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this string `the symbol for four is 4 like in 34. _1234_`. How can regex match the individual `4` and the `4` in `34` but not the one between the two `_` characters in `_1234_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are not very specific, so sorry if [this](https://regex101.com/r/pI8lE5/2) will not work in practice for the actual application.

```
/(?:(?:^|\b)[^\_][a-zA-Z0-9]*)(4)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*[^\_](?:\b|$))/g
```

It checks every word that it does not begin and end with underscores for a 4.

Comment: thanks, but in your example it matchs the spaces around the 4 and a period. If that can be prevented it should work.

Comment: The actual extract should be a 4 as it's the only thing in a capturing group. It just highlights the part of the string that matches the regex

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<!_\d*)4(?!\d*_)
```

It makes sure the `4` is neither followed nor follows any count of digits and then an underscore.
**Edit:** I'm sorry, this won't work because JS does not support negative lookbehinds.

Comment: Yes, I just realised it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Look for `_\d+_|(4)`, and check for a match with the (4) group.  Since the alternatives in | are tried left-to-right, the (4) group will only match 4s that aren't in numbers surrounded by underscores